# libcurl does not work with http redirect

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

I developed an application that use libcurl as a http client.

I tried to conncet to a HTTP server, the server return http redirect to another address, but the libcurl do nothing after receiving the http redirect.

What I m missing?

my code:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, userid);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, passwd);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC|CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, header_list);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
```

here after the traffic log:

```
GET /openacs/ HTTP/1.1

Host: 192.168.1.110:8080

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Language: fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Connection: keep-alive



HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently

Location: http://192.168.1.133:8080/openacs/acs

Date: Thu, 09 Feb 2012 15:33:15 GMT

Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu)

Content-Length: 0

Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Answer (score 5):

You also need to set the [`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTFOLLOWLOCATION) flag to tell curl to automatically follow redirects:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
```

Comment: I tried and it works. in the second connection to the server with the old server address, the libcurl connect with the old address and not with new addres. I expect that libcurl will always use the new address in the new connections because he get redirect `301 Moved Permanently`

Comment: MOHAMED, you have to think on each connection as independent processes. You are own your own for detecting redirects and the new hostname. I won't do it obvious security reasons